# Can anyone tell me the formula to sum up expenses added "today" to the category "recharge"?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

[image]

This is my personal finance manager spreadsheet I made with google sheets.

Can anyone tell me the formula to sum up expenses added "today" to the category "recharge" ?

p.s I know to pull the sum using a specific date.That's not what I want. I need the cell to sum up the expenses of the day I am viewing the sheet. The value needs to get updated according to  each day's expenses. Please look at the formula I tried using.

Answer (score 0):

In your last argument you can you today().

sumifs askes for

criteria_range1, criterion1

it is asking when does criteria_range1 = criterion1